# How to distinguish activity on an account?

Tags: reporting, activities

We have 2 workflows that collide:

1. Sales team are looking for neglected accounts, based on "Last Activity" < last 6 months.
2. Marketing team are sending mass emails through campaigns etc, to the same accounts, however, once they do, that account's "Last Activity" is updated with the sent email/task

That interferes with sales team. And I can't figure a way to get by this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about custom date field which will hold "Last modification date".
This field will be updated in trigger only if user who triggered update is not from Marketing team.